# What times do the Sydney international and domestic airports open and close?

Tags: australia, airports, sydney, syd, opening-hours

Sydney airport is a complex containing both the international airport and the domestic airport, but unlike many other busy airports neither part is open 24 hours.

I usually work in a backpacker hostel in Sydney so I've dug up this information for guests who wanted to sleep at the airport to catch 6am flights numerous times, but right now I'm having a lot of trouble finding the details.

**During which hours are Sydney Domestic and Sydney International closed overnight?**

Comment: My first hand experience of "sleeping" at the Sydney international terminal is that they purposefully make the in-terminal seating as unsuitable as reasonably possible for sleeping , they do ticket and passport checks at closing time and let bona-fide travellers linger miserably for some more hours and then at maybe 2am-3am ? kick you out into a cold windy shelter - again designed to be inhospitable. || I arrived after having had 1st my baggage and then me lost on a nightmare  ??? hour trip from China (30+ hours?)(maybe not) with no clothes apart from long trousers and a long sleeved shirt...

Comment: ... STUPID and never again. I ended up putting a newspaper layer inside my shirt and still froze. Not enough paper to make a decent blanket when others wanted it too. A single newspaper layer over you when just above zero roof is radiating coolth works wonders :-). Better solution is catch a train (from AT airport to town etc and find a hostel for the night). I was travelling next day to Gold Coast and stayed with others mainly for "solidarity" but regretted the gesture :-).

Comment: FWIW: I now when out of NZ ALWAYS carry a lightweight synthetic jacket which is ~ 0 weight and ~ 0 volume and astoundingly good at saving ones life. ALWAYS :-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Murphy's Law dictates, the very next Google search I did for this info after giving up and submitting it as a question here, was successful!

[From the Sydney Airport website](http://www.sydneyairport.com.au/find/service-categories/service-listing/service-detail?cat=%7B8491D25E-92CD-4199-AB97-6E2E97FB1997%7D&ser=%7BA2A3B418-80CF-4121-9450-10E59670B6DB%7D):

> Sydney Airport opening times are:
>
> **T1 International terminal** is opened everyday from **3AM to 11:00PM** (0300 to 2300)
>   • Customs are opened for departures passenger processing at 4AM daily (0400)
>
> **T2 Domestic terminal** is opened everyday from **4AM to 11:00PM** (0400 to 2300)

Comment: So I wonder what happens if you're trying to sleep there - will they just turf you outside?

Comment: @MarkMayo: I encourage you to branch off a new question!

Comment: @MarkMayo Not from firsthand experience, but I have no doubt they would boot you out.